# Rails 5 rendering partials and passing data

Tags: ruby, templates, ruby-on-rails-5, partial

I'm having trouble getting traction on what the general ways data gets passed around from and is made available to partials.

For example:

I have a controller handing off an instance variable to a template that renders a partial:

static_pages_controller.rb:

```
def home
  @feed_items = current_user.feed
end
```

home.html.erb:

```
<%= render 'shared/feed' %>
```

_feed.html.erb:

```
<%= render @feed_items %>
```

Now, inside my User model is an instance method that reaching into the database to get her posts:

user.rb:

```
def feed
  Micropost.where("user_id = ?", id)
end
```

So somehow because `Micropost.where(...)` returns a collection of microposts is that how Rails knows to go from `_feed.html.erb` to another partial where the `<li>` is defined for how microposts want to be defined?

_micropost.html.erb:

```
<li id="micropost-<%= micropost.id %>">
  <%= link_to adorable_avatar_for(micropost.user, size: 50), micropost.user %>
</li>
```

And also is it just a convention that because I'm really handling a collection of `microposts` that Rails knows to give the `micropost` variable?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your questions are answered in the [Ruby on Rails Guides on Layouts and Rendering](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/layouts_and_rendering.html#using-partials).  It's worth reading the information on partials that comes before the quoted passages below as well:

> Every partial also has a local variable with the same name as the
>   partial (minus the underscore). You can pass an object in to this
>   local variable via the :object option:
>
> ```
> <%= render partial: "customer", object: @new_customer %>
> ```
>
> Within the customer partial, the customer variable will refer to
>   @new_customer from the parent view. (Earlier the Guide instructs that to specify other options for render(), e.g. object:, you have to explicitly specify `partial:` and the name of the partial.)
>
> If you have an instance of a model to render into a partial, you can
>   use a shorthand syntax:
>
> ```
> <%= render @customer %>
> ```
>
> Assuming that the @customer instance variable contains an instance of
>   the Customer model, this will use _customer.html.erb to render it and
>   will pass the local variable customer into the partial which will
>   refer to the @customer instance variable in the parent view.
>
> 3.4.5 Rendering Collections
>
> Partials are very useful in rendering collections. When you pass a
>   collection to a partial via the :collection option, the partial will
>   be inserted once for each member in the collection:
>
> index.html.erb:
>
> ```
> <h1>Products</h1>
> <%= render partial: "product", collection: @products %>
> ```
>
> _product.html.erb:
>
> ```
> <p>Product Name: <%= product.name %></p>
> ```
>
> When a partial is called with a pluralized collection, then the
>   individual instances of the partial have access to the member of the
>   collection being rendered via a variable named after the partial. In
>   this case, the partial is _product, and within the _product partial,
>   you can refer to product to get the instance that is being rendered.
>
> There is also a shorthand for this. Assuming @products is a collection
>   of product instances, you can simply write this in the index.html.erb
>   to produce the same result:
>
> ```
> <h1>Products</h1>
> <%= render @products %>
> ```
>
> Rails determines the name of the partial to use by looking at the
>   model name in the collection. In fact, you can even create a
>   heterogeneous collection and render it this way, and Rails will choose
>   the proper partial for each member of the collection:
>
> index.html.erb:
>
> ```
> <h1>Contacts</h1>
> <%= render [customer1, employee1, customer2, employee2] %>
> ```
>
> customers/_customer.html.erb:
>
> ```
> <p>Customer: <%= customer.name %></p>
> ```
>
> employees/_employee.html.erb:
>
> ```
> <p>Employee: <%= employee.name %></p>
> ```
>
> In this case, Rails will use the customer or employee partials as
>   appropriate for each member of the collection.
>
> In the event that the collection is empty, render will return nil, so
>   it should be fairly simple to provide alternative content.
>
> ```
> <h1>Products</h1>
> <%= render(@products) || "There are no products available." %>
> ```