# How to pass a url path to a form_with partial in Rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I'm trying to render the form and pass url and method into it

home/index.html.erb

```
<%= render partial: "rides/form", locals: { url: rides_path, method: :post } %>
```

rides/_form.html.erb

```
<%= form_for(action: @ride, local: true, url: url, method: method) do |form| %>
```

Error:

```
undefined local variable or method `url' for #<#<Class:0x00007fec9aae15f8>:0x00007fec9ab30e00>
Did you mean?  URI
```

Comment: Oops, sorry I messed up the link, check this: https://stackoverflow.com/a/40956945/5239030

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You dont need to pass a `*_path` helper, they are available everywhere in the views.

Answer (score 2):

Rails is super magic and if you are using an existing instance variable (@ride), you shouldn't have to explicitly pass in the URL. Try

`<%= render "rides/form" %>` in your home/index.html.erb file

and in your 'rides/_form.html.erb' use:

`<%= form_for @ride do |f| %>`...

The form_for helper should automatically send data via POST to the #update action in your Rides controller.

You can read more about it here

http://api.rubyonrails.org/v5.0/classes/ActionView/Helpers/FormHelper.html

Comment: Thank you. There was also a problem, I had an error: "First argument in form cannot contain nil or be empty". I changed @ride to Ride.new in the form_for